# How do I cast an HtmlGenericControl as a WebControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

... I am trying to dynamically add or remove classes to my ASP controls using this code (which I found via my great pair-programming friend who shall be known as 'Mr G')

```
public static class WebHelper
{
    public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass) {
        List<string> classes;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass)) 
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            if (!classes.Contains(cssClass))
                classes.Add(cssClass);
        }
        else
        {
            classes = new List<string> { cssClass };
        }
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }

    public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass))
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        classes.Remove(cssClass);
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to pass my HtmlGenericControls to them... I've tried the obvious:

```
WebControl test1 = (WebControl)Page.FindControl("divcontent");
WebHelper.AddCssClass(test1, centredClass);
```

But I get:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl'.

I'm still relatively inexperienced at C#, Visual Studio etc as my background is Ye Olde Pick BASIC, so please explain simply how I either cast my control, or amend the code so it will achieve the end goal of being able to add or remove classes without losing any existing ones.

Many thanks! Ross

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using your friends class wrong. Methods in your WebHelper are extension methods, so it should look like this:

```
WebControl test1 = (WebControl)Page.FindControl("divcontent");
test1.AddCssClass("something");
```

(verified that it works). Make sure your control derives from `WebControl` and it has `runat="server"` set.

**Edit: modified WebHelper to support HtmlControls as well**

```
public static class WebHelper
{
    public static void AddCssClass(this HtmlControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Attributes["class"]))
        {
            classes = control.Attributes["class"].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            if (!classes.Contains(cssClass))
                classes.Add(cssClass);
        }
        else
        {
            classes = new List<string> { cssClass };
        }
        control.Attributes["class"] = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }

    public static void RemoveCssClass(this HtmlControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Attributes["class"]))
        {
            classes = control.Attributes["class"].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        classes.Remove(cssClass);
        control.Attributes["class"] = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }

    public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass))
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            if (!classes.Contains(cssClass))
                classes.Add(cssClass);
        }
        else
        {
            classes = new List<string> { cssClass };
        }
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }

    public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass))
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        classes.Remove(cssClass);
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Feel free to modify the code as needed. Everything remained the same, just added extension methods for HtmlControl, because if you want to modify a class of HtmlControl, you need to work with `control.Attributes["class"]`, as there is no `CssClass` attribute. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, Thanks for pointing out I'm calling it incorrectly.
I don't know if I can make the control derive from WebControl... it looks like this in the page:     
    <div class="divcontent" id="divcontent" runat="server">
I'm still getting the exception as it stands.

Comment: @RossBrooker, simple change div to asp:Panel should resolve your problems when applied on along with my example.

Comment: Ohhhhh.  That's a bit frightening as I've got a whole existing website full of divs.  I can't realistically change all of them to panels just to make the helpers work properly.

Comment: @RossBrooker, sure, in that case let my try to modify the code. Be right back! :)

Comment: thankyou! I'm out of the office for a couple of hours from now, I'll look forward to trying it out :)

Comment: @RossBrooker, done! Hope it helps. Verified the method AddCssClass and it worked with <div id="..." runat="server"> correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asp:Panel` control for `divcontent` instead of `div runat="server"`